# Http Akka route with regular expression is not compiling

Tags: regex, scala, url-routing, akka-http

I am using Http Akka with Scala.
I have this route:

```
object Route {
  val route =

    path("items" / "card" / """\w+""".r) {
      get {
        complete {
          EntitiesData.someEntity
        }
      }
    }
}
```

For some reason it doesn't compile with this error:

```
Error:(18, 11) type mismatch;
 found   : akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
    (which expands to)  akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]
 required: String => (akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext => scala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult])
      get {
```

When I remove the regular expression part or change it to a regular string things seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your code to be:

```
object Route {
  val route =

    path("items" / "card" / """\w+""".r) { matched =>
      get {
        complete {
          EntitiesData.someEntity
        }
      }
    }
}
```

From the Akka PathMatcher DSL docs:

> You can use a Regex instance as a PathMatcher1[String], which matches
>   whatever the regex matches and extracts one String value. A
>   PathMatcher created from a regular expression extracts either the
>   complete match (if the regex doesn't contain a capture group) or the
>   capture group (if the regex contains exactly one capture group). If
>   the regex contains more than one capture group an
>   IllegalArgumentException will be thrown.

So when you use a regex in a path directive, it will pass along the matched part into the sections under that directive.  That was what was missing from your code.